# In which sense Linearizability extends Atomicity?

Tags: concurrency, atomic

I read in the literature that Linearizability *extends* Atomicity. My question is:

> In which sense Linearizability extends Atomicity?

I think atomicity is defined for one object of type read/write storage; however, linearizability is defined for one or more objects (even the objects can have different types). Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: "Atomicity" is not _really_ an attribute of any data type. It's an attribute of an _operation_ on data. When some programming language allows you to declare some "atomic" type, what that means is that certain operations on the data will be done atomically. (RTFM to find out which operations.) "Linearizability" is a property of a _sequence_ of operations, and an atomic operation, by definition, is a single operation (i.e., a sequence of one.) So, it makes sense to say that an atomic operations is trivially linearizable.